# How to pass dynamic params in SSHOperator in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

I want to run a task running every day with a datetime param. e.g. `python flow 20190801`, so the date is a dynamic param.

I tried it in `jinja` template, but it seemed not working(can't read the `{{ DATE }}` param).
What's the problem there? Or is there any better solution for achieving the same purpose?

Here is the snippet.

```py
compress_task = SSHOperator(
    task_id='test_task',
    ssh_conn_id='exporter_ssh',
    depends_on_past=True,
    command='python flows.py compress -d {{ DATE }} ',
    params={"DATE": str(datetime.today().date()).replace('-', '')},
    dag=dag
)
```

I know one of the solution is using `$(date '+%Y%m%d')`, but it is always the current execute date, not the task scheduled date.

Answer (score 2):

I just get to know it can be implemented [with macros](http://airflow.apache.org/macros.html).

```py
compress_task = SSHOperator(
    task_id='test_task',
    ssh_conn_id='exporter_ssh',
    depends_on_past=True,
    command='python flows.py compress -d {{ ds_nodash }}',
    dag=dag
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use parameters specified in `params` dictionary for Jinja templating, then you need to access them by referencing `params` first, i.e. `{{ params.DATE }}`. Thus in your case, it should be

```py
compress_task = SSHOperator(
    task_id='test_task',
    ssh_conn_id='exporter_ssh',
    depends_on_past=True,
    command='python flows.py compress -d {{ params.DATE }} ',
    params={"DATE": str(datetime.today().date()).replace('-', '')},
    dag=dag
)
```

However, when it comes to timestamps and dates related to execution of tasks/dags, then it is better to use [built-in macros](http://airflow.apache.org/macros.html) as you have already pointed out.